# Feature as seen in iPad Twitter App (popup navigation controller)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, popup

I am wondering how the feature twitter uses in their iPad app works. It's the feature when you select Profile on the left side. Then select "Edit Profile..." There's a segue that pops the Edit Profile box to the center of the viewing area (while the rest is dimmed). Then, if you select to edit the name, you go to a new screen without changing the background.

I know this is in a navigation controller but how are they doing the navigation controller where it's a smaller view and you can still see the rest of the app in the background? I can do this fine when all my popup views are called via addSubview.

I currently have a nav controller -> view controller (with tableview filling up the whole page & multiple uiviews that are popped up with addSubview. I don't what the UIPopOverController feature.

I've tried to add another nav controller off my VC but I cannot control the size.

Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: add a picture if you want people to know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
    UIViewController *mainViewController = your main view controller;
    ...
    UINavigationController *formViewController = whatever you want to appear in the little box;
    formViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet;
    [mainViewController presentViewController:formViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

See the docs for more information on modalPresentationStyle:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html